# woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation hook works for variable product, but not for single

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use the following hook

```
function dvpi_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations ) {
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'dvpi_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

For a product of the 'variable' type, this works

---

The problem is that if the type of the product is 'single', this hook is also executed but expected 3 params, otherwise I get this error message:

```
function dvpi_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'dvpi_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function dvpi_add_to_cart_validation(), 3 passed in /data/sites/web/.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 5 expected in...

And if condition in the function where I am going to check on the product type 'comes too late'.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change your function parameter to optional like below & check for both single & variation products if it works or not.

```
function dvpi_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = 0, $variations = null) {
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'dvpi_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```